# Flex item width can not work in IE11 when container have right scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Here is a example

```css
.FlexContainer {
 background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-height: 220px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 300px;
 overflow-y: auto;
}

.FlexItem {
 background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
 width: 80%;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 6px;
 word-break: break-all;
 white-space: normal;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.FlexItem:hover{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="FlexContainer">
    <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents is short in IE11.
    </div>
    <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents is long - inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
 <div class="FlexItem">
        The contents inside of this box are overflowing their container in IE11.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome it can work well
[chrome work well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkVYK.png)

But In IE11 It's not what I expected. 
[IE11 work not expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQavL.png)

This issue only happen when container height is less than fex items and set overflow-y:auto/scroll.

Is anyone can help me find the cause of the issue?

Appreciate for your help.

Comment: IE is known to have a lot of flex-bugs... `width: 80%` on the `FlexItem` is causing the issue, you have the same issue in IE11 if you give `align-self: flex-start` to it... perhaps you can avoid setting width here :)

Comment: I try to set width: auto, It can work. All items are expanded to 100%.  But if set width:100%(or other percentages), The result is the same as described above. I do not know why.

Comment: IE11 has issue with setting width like that in a flexbox, tried `flex-basis: 80%`?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer needs you to specify the flex value of you children.
Try to add the property `flex: 1 0 auto;` to the `FlexItem` class

Comment: Actually I don't see why you want to use flex for your example. A simple `block`display should do the trick. Maybe you can try `flex: 1 0 0;` in your `FlexItem`class

Comment: I encounter a similar issue in a my product, This is only an example base on the components used in the project. So display: flex is necessary condition.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the key point maybe the format of setting the width of FlexItem.

If you change the width:80% as 200px, it will work well in IE.

I guess that if you write in % format, IE may could not understand it well.

So you should give a static length to it.

[image: Working in IE]

Comment: Yes, percentages witdh can not work. I was asked to use responsive width, so can not use a static width. Only can set "width:auto;" now.

Thanks for your answer.